# PhpMailer not sending mails - TLS error?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a problem sending emails with phpmailer .

The code that sends emails is:

```
$mail_User      = "site@xxxxxxx.com";
$mail_Password  = "My Password";
$mail_address   = "site@xxxxxxx.com";
$mail_Name      = "MyName";
$mail_Server    = "222.222.222.222";
$mail_Port      = 25;

    function SendHTMLMail($to, $cc, $bcc, $subject, $body)
    {
        global $mail_User, $mail_Password, $mail_address, $mail_Name, $mail_Server, $mail_Port;
        $correo = new PHPMailer;
        $correo->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
        $correo->SetLanguage("es", "/phpmailer/language/");
        $correo->IsSMTP();

        $correo->IsHTML(true);
        $correo->Host = $mail_Server;
        $correo->Port = $mail_Port;
        $correo->SMTPAuth =true;
        //$correo->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $correo->Username = $mail_User;
        $correo->Password = $mail_Password;
        $correo->From      = $mail_address;
        $correo->FromName  = $mail_Name;
        $correo->Subject = $subject;
        $correo->Body    = $body;
        $dest = explode (";", $to);
        for ($n=0; isset($dest[$n]); $n++) $correo->AddAddress($dest[$n]);
        $dest = explode (";", $cc);
        for ($n=0; isset($dest[$n]); $n++) $correo->AddCC($dest[$n]);
        $dest = explode (";", $bcc);
        for ($n=0; isset($dest[$n]); $n++) $correo->AddBCC($dest[$n]);
        if ($correo->Send())
            return "";
        else {
            AddLog("Correo no enviado: $correo->ErrorInfo");
            echo "<br>Correo no enviado: $correo->ErrorInfo<br>";
            return "Correo no enviado: $correo->ErrorInfo";
        }
    }
```

And the result is :

```
2016-02-24 04:58:17 Connection: opening to 222.222.222.222:25, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2016-02-24 04:58:17 Connection: opened
2016-02-24 04:58:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-srv1.abcdef.com ESMTP Exim 4.86 #2 Wed, 24 Feb 2016 14:47:17 +0100 
                                      220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
                                      220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2016-02-24 04:58:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.site.com
2016-02-24 04:58:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-srv1.abcdef.com Hello www.doznyk.com [181.181.181.181]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250 HELP
2016-02-24 04:58:18 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2016-02-24 04:58:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2016-02-24 04:58:18 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2016-02-24 04:58:18 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-02-24 04:58:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 srv1.abcdef.com closing connection
2016-02-24 04:58:19 Connection: closed
2016-02-24 04:58:19 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Why phpmailer don't send emails? Why it try to use TLS if the code line is a comment?

I replace sensitive data with fake, like server name and IPs.
If I change port from 25 to 587 and uncomment the line tls, the result is almost the same.

Thank you

---

New test, same result.

I read the doc as  Synchro suggest me. 
I changed the port from 25 to 587 and added the line $correo->SMTPAutoTLS = true;

```
$correo->SMTPAuth =true;
$correo->SMTPAutoTLS = true;
//$correo->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$correo->Username = $mail_User;
$correo->Password = $mail_Password;
```

The result is:

```
2016-02-24 06:05:36 Connection: opening to 222.222.222.222:587, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2016-02-24 06:05:37 Connection: opened
2016-02-24 06:05:37 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-srv1.abcdef.com ESMTP Exim 4.86 #2 Wed, 24 Feb 2016 15:54:37 +0100 
                                      220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
                                      220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2016-02-24 06:05:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.myserver.com
2016-02-24 06:05:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-srv1.abcdef.com Hello www.doznyk.com [181.229.171.247]
                                      250-SIZE 52428800
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
                                      250-STARTTLS
                                      250 HELP
2016-02-24 06:05:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2016-02-24 06:05:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2016-02-24 06:05:39 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2016-02-24 06:05:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-02-24 06:05:39 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 srv1.abcdef.com closing connection
2016-02-24 06:05:39 Connection: closed
```

Comment: You need to read the docs it pointed you at. It will tell you exactly why it's using TLS (it's opportunistic) and how to deal with it.

Comment: What type of authentication do you have at the mail server? It might be causing problems because it's expecting a secure connection...

Comment: I can use tls or none.
if I comment the line "//$correo->SMTPSecure = 'tls';" Security is none.
if I uncomment that line, phpmailer use TLS

Comment: I debug the code inside phpmailer, and I found that the trouble seem to be in function startTLS()
the line
 if (!stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->smtp_conn, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT))
 return false whatever I use TLS or not.

Comment: Make sure the ports are open outbound on your server

Comment: Yes, those ports (25, 587) are open.
If there are not open, the **Connection: opened** had not been logged. 
Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well. I made a lot of test and cannot see the section of doc that said me Synchro, but Synchro was right.

I added the next code and now works fine!

```
$correo->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

Although I do not use SSL, I must clarify that I don't use SSL because phpmailer verifies that SSL is usable.
Or must be configured properly

Thanks!

Comment: Although SSL is not in use, It must be correctly configured or disabled with those lines.

Comment: Thank You captain, you saved another life.

Comment: Tank you very much :)

Comment: Yo are Welcome.

Comment: it works ..."ssl" => Array ()... even with TLS connections:   `$mail->Port = 587;    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = true $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` !